# Windows 7 stops sending DNS packets at seemingly random times

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, wireshark

Pinging an IP directly (and just about any other direct IP connection) seems to pass through.

On the other hand, when pinging a domain, using chrome to enter a website or attempting to use nslookup for debugging, this is the result:

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup google.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

The weird thing is, that sniffing on wireshark showed **no DNS packets being sent** at all. Not by nslookup, not by chrome and not by anything else. There is occasionally a DNS request that gets sent, and even gets answered but for the vast majority of the time, nada.

I have just a single network interface, and upon restarting it, the problem fixes itself temporarily.

DNS is configured to 8.8.8.8 prim and 8.8.4.4 sec.

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Bar-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ether
net Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 20-CF-30-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9a3:8043:80b0:3350%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.17(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.138
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 2370XXXX
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-XX-XX-XX-XX

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2758E2BA-5AD9-42BD-BF21-7FEDAF516EE9}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I tried updating and rollbacking the driver to no avail.

The Tcpip reg key also seems fine.

Disabled Kaspersky Internet Security and Windows Firewall. Did not help.

Comment: nslookup and ping do not work the same way. ping uses the standard resolver chain and does a lot more when attempting to resolve a hostname than nslookup does. The failure with nslookup you're seeing has to do with a lack of a PTR, see here: https://www.cbfive.com/ping-vs-nslookup/
I'd honestly use dig instead of nslookup: http://www.isc.org/software/bind The downloads include windows executable. It is really a FAR better DNS program.

Comment: @MaQleod Thanks mate, did not know that. However, the problem exists in all programs. Edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Could AV software be intercepting the traffics and be broken?

Comment: Thought about both AV and firewall. Did not help.